# Dependency Injected StackExchange.Redis Client

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, redis, .net-core

I am currently building cache for my application, and I would like to have my redis cache client work the same way you would dependency inject a DbContext.

I am using StackExchange.Redis to manage my redis cache:
https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis

I have made it work, but I am not very confident in the way I implemented it.

In my services I have added:

```cs
        services.AddSingleton<IConnectionMultiplexer(ConnectionMultiplexer
            .Connect("localhost:6379,allowAdmin=true"));

        services.AddScoped<ICacheClient, CacheClient>();
```

I could not figure out how to add IDatabase to services.

My CacheClient looks like this:

```cs
    public class CacheClient : ICacheClient
    {
        private readonly IConnectionMultiplexer _connectionMultiplexer;
        private readonly IDatabase _redisCache;
        private readonly ISerializer _serializer;

        public CacheClient(IConnectionMultiplexer connectionMultiplexer, ISerializer serializer)
        {
            _connectionMultiplexer = connectionMultiplexer;
            _serializer = serializer;
            _redisCache = connectionMultiplexer.GetDatabase();
        }

        //add/set cache methods removed for the sake of brevity.

    }
```

From here I can use _redisCache to access the database and do operations such as _redisCache.StringSetAsync etc...

Now ICacheClient can be injected into my application and I can use my cache logic in any class. Which is very nice.

Is there anything wrong with this way of implementing my cache client?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can share with you an example version of Redis service such as getting subscribers or accessing the other databases and also for catching connection issues.

`ConfigurationOptions` allows us to initialize service with more Redis servers(Redis pool), if needed you can easily change the constructor parameters.

Note that `ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect();` is `already static` method, so you can initialize service in class when needed as I did below.

In Addition, I assume that you take `ISerializer` for the object serialization, if it is, I added an example of `serialize`/`deserialize` for you.

I hope it helps you.

```c#
    public class CacheClient : ICacheClient
    {
        private readonly ConfigurationOptions configuration = null;
        private Lazy<IConnectionMultiplexer> _Connection = null;

        public CacheClient(string host = "localhost", int port = 6379, bool allowAdmin = false)
        {
            configuration = new ConfigurationOptions()
            {
                //for the redis pool so you can extent later if needed
                EndPoints = { { host, port }, },
                AllowAdmin = allowAdmin,
                //Password = "", //to the security for the production
                ClientName = "My Redis Client",
                ReconnectRetryPolicy = new LinearRetry(5000),
                AbortOnConnectFail = false,
            };
            _Connection = new Lazy<IConnectionMultiplexer>(() =>
            {
                ConnectionMultiplexer redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(configuration);
                //redis.ErrorMessage += _Connection_ErrorMessage;
                //redis.InternalError += _Connection_InternalError;
                //redis.ConnectionFailed += _Connection_ConnectionFailed;
                //redis.ConnectionRestored += _Connection_ConnectionRestored;
                return redis;
            });
        }

        //for the 'GetSubscriber()' and another Databases
        public IConnectionMultiplexer Connection { get { return _Connection.Value; } }

        //for the default database
        public IDatabase Database => Connection.GetDatabase();

        public T JsonGet<T>(RedisKey key, CommandFlags flags = CommandFlags.None)
        {
            RedisValue rv = Database.StringGet(key, flags);
            if (!rv.HasValue)
                return default;
            T rgv = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(rv);
            return rgv;
        }

        public bool JsonSet(RedisKey key, object value, TimeSpan? expiry = null, When when = When.Always, CommandFlags flags = CommandFlags.None)
        {
            if (value == null) return false;
            return Database.StringSet(key, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value), expiry, when, flags);
        }
        private void _Connection_ErrorMessage(object sender, RedisErrorEventArgs e)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        //add/set cache methods removed for the sake of brevity.
    }
```

**Adding Service**

```c#
 services.AddSingleton<ICacheClient>(new CacheClient(allowAdmin:true));
```

Comment: Very nice, I have been looking for something to handle the case when the redis server is not up.

Right now a request throws and error if the redis server is down. Id like to have it just fall back to SQL if it is not up. I will try to implement this.

Comment: i am also using this code and i am updating the code when i have changed it. if you see better solution please share with me. this is my best solution too.